# Print the contents of a text file on the client's printer using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, printing, client-side

I am having a text file uploaded on the server.

When a User Clicks on print button I want the file to be printed using his/her printer.

Currently I am using the below code, but it is for the server side printing.

```
Protected Sub btnPrint_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnPrint.Click

        Dim fileName As String = ""

        For x As Integer = 0 To FileImageList.Count - 1

            If FileImageList(x).parent.backcolor = Drawing.Color.Orange Then
                fileName = FileNameList(x).text
            End If

        Next

        ReadFile(fileName, Server.MapPath("~\Medical\Users\" & Session("DocumentUploader") & "\Uploaded\"))
        printDocument1.Print()

    End Sub

Private Sub printDocument1_PrintPage(ByVal sender As Object, _
        ByVal e As PrintPageEventArgs)

        Dim charactersOnPage As Integer = 0
        Dim linesPerPage As Integer = 0
        Dim font As System.Drawing.Font = New Font("Times New Roman", 14, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)

        ' Sets the value of charactersOnPage to the number of characters  
        ' of stringToPrint that will fit within the bounds of the page.
        e.Graphics.MeasureString(stringToPrint, font, e.MarginBounds.Size, _
            StringFormat.GenericTypographic, charactersOnPage, linesPerPage)

        ' Draws the string within the bounds of the page
        e.Graphics.DrawString(stringToPrint, font, Brushes.Black, _
            e.MarginBounds, StringFormat.GenericTypographic)

        ' Remove the portion of the string that has been printed.
        stringToPrint = stringToPrint.Substring(charactersOnPage)

        ' Check to see if more pages are to be printed.
        e.HasMorePages = stringToPrint.Length > 0

    End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Javascript [print function](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/article.php/3471121/Print-a-Web-Page-Using-JavaScript.htm) of the `window` object.

Comment: I tried your suggession just now. But It prints the whole page. I want to print the contents of a text file.

Comment: You need to have a page that shows only the content you want printed, and then call the `print` function in that page. Sites like Wikipedia, for example, have a "printer friendly" version of every page, which is exactly what seems to be you rneed.

Comment: Ya But it prints the half page only. See the images attached in the question after 2 minutes.

Comment: Are you sure it's not an issue with printer setting? Like paper feed size and margins?

Comment: It cant be the issue as I am trying to print it using Microsoft XPS Document Viewer.

Comment: I've just seen the image. The problem is the HTML container holding your content. You need to style it so that it is more printer friendly. Avoid textboxes, and also avoid any HTML containers with fixed widths. If you're concerned about restyling, remember that only the printer friendly page needs to be styled like that.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I will just try your opinion and let you know.